# Uncaught Reference error

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have this code in my head

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function alertSize() {
    // Get Browser Viewport Width
    var adjust = "<?php echo $adjust; ?>";
    // Get Browser Viewport Height
    var height = window.innerHeight ||
    document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
    document.body.clientHeight;
    // Get Browser Viewport Height
    var height = window.getSize().y;

}
window.onload = alertSize;


</script>
```

and I have this in my body

```
<div id="bodyheight">

                </div>
                <script language="JavaScript">
                document.getElementById("bodyheight").style.height = height;</script>
```

yet I get in the body code:

> 'Uncaught ReferenceError: height is not defined'

In the head code I know that the height has a value as when I output 'height' as a pop up the correct value is displayed.

I know that the 'document.getElementById("bodyheight").style.height = ;' works when I place a fixed value in place of the 'height' variable.

But for some reason I cannot get the 'height' variable to work in `document.getElementById("bodyheight").style.height = height;`.

Comment: scratch that, i have a response from another post.... solved withwindow.onload=function() {
// Get Browser Viewport Width
    var adjust = "200";
    // Get Browser Viewport Height
    var height = window.innerHeight ||
    document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
    document.body.clientHeight;
    // Get Browser Viewport Height
    height = (window.getSize)? window.getSize().y:height;
    var newHeight = (height - adjust) + 'px' 
    window.alert(height+' adjusted to '+newHeight);
    document.getElementById("bodyheight").style.height = newHeight;
}

Answer (score 1):

`height` is a function-local variable, and can only be used from within `alertSize()`.  Your inline script is attempting to use it, but this variable is not in scope at that point.

Additionally, note that you use the `var` statement twice to create the `height` variable.  You are redeclaring a local variable, and this is considered by many developers to be an error.

Answer (score 0):

Variable scope
try

```
var height;
function alertSize() {
    // Get Browser Viewport Width
    var adjust = "<?php echo $adjust; ?>";
    // Get Browser Viewport Height
    height = window.innerHeight ||
    document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
    document.body.clientHeight;
    // Get Browser Viewport Height
    height = window.getSize().y;

}
```

more info here: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

hope this helps